# CodeIgniter Callback not working for user login

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2, codeigniter-form-helper

I have checked all questions of this type but none of them works for me. Hope I would get some help here. I have a controller named index and a model named Index_model. I have write user login and signup functions in the index controller and done data related queries in model everything is working fine except the codeigniter callback function.

When I try to validete user login details by using the callback each time it returns false and when I removed callback it is working fine. I am not getting where I am doing wrong. Please find the code below for my controller and model. Thanks in advance.

Controller:

```
class Index extends CI_Controller{

    public function __construct(){
        parent:: __construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->model('index_model');
    }

   public function signin(){
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $data['title'] = "Sign In";
        $data['headline'] = "Sign In";
        $data['introduction'] = "Sign In to manage your business, clients and more!";
        $data['include'] = "user/signin";
        $this->load->view('template/template', $data);
    }

    public function login(){
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|callback_validate_login');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');

        if($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE){
            $data['msg'] = "User Login Successfully!!";
            $this->load->view('user/home', $data);
        }else{
            $this->signin();
        }

    }

    public function validate_login(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $result = $this->index_model->validate_user();
        if($result == TRUE){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_login', 'Incorrect username / password.');
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Model:

```
class Index_model extends CI_Model{
    public function __construct(){
        $this->load->database();
    }

    /******User Login*************/
    public function validate_user(){
        $username = $this->input->post('username');
        $password = $this->input->post('password');

        $this->db->where('username', $username);
        $this->db->where('password', $password);
        $query = $this->db->get('user');

        if($query->num_rows() == 1){
            return TRUE;
        }else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }
}
```

Please, review My code it will be a great help.

Comment: are you storing raw password ?????

Comment: what your function validate_user() is returning

Comment: validate_user check whether the user with the username and password exists in the database as you can see $username and $password consist of the POST data

Comment: i mean,is it returning true on correct username and password ???did you check it?

Comment: I have check it but it return False each time if I removed the callback and validate fields directly its working fine.

Comment: did you store your password as raw string or you perform some hashing on it?????

Comment: Why people give down vote to this question if they even don't know the solution

Answer (score 0):

You must get the parameter you are passing to the function using callback which is in this case the username. so change your code to this:

```
public function validate_login($username){ # get the parameter
    $this->load->library('form_validation'); # you do not need this line here

    $result = $this->index_model->validate_user($username); #chek the parameter
    if($result == TRUE){
        return TRUE;
    }else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('validate_login', 'Incorrect username / password.');
        return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why I need to pass username here in the validate_login ? This function only returns the true or false based on the function validate_user that is written in the model. Is there any specific reason due to which you passed variable in the validate_login? It will be great if you describe it because I am not getting it's reason

Comment: yes, this is encoded inside the callback functions, they pass the value of the field that they are validating to the callback function for process! https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html

Comment: But I am not going to validate field with a static data My concern is to validate username and password by using the function written in the model as you can also see in the code

Comment: It is not a static data, the `validate_login()` function will process what ever is filled from the view by the user!

Comment: Ok getting you point and I think it will be much better if I removed callback and validate user directly by passing the username and password to the model function validate_user. I have another query is that how can I set the message for specific field by using  the set_message. Currently its used with the callback but now I am not using the callback so how can I display a message to the user that the username and password is incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

you should use

```
$this->db->where('password', md5($password)); 
/* you should use md5($password) instead of just $password since you are using md5 as hashing technique */
```

you have used

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');
```

password gets converted to `md5` after the validation is run and not in the callback process

```
$this->form_validation->run() //i.e. after this
```

**Note :** md5 is not at all secure now a days. beware of rainbow table attacks.
better change the hashing technique. there are a lot of questions regarding the password hashing & security in SO.

Answer (score 0):

Just make few change in your code

```
$this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5');
```

remove md5 from here and add md5 function where your password matched your database table field

In validate_user function

```
$this->db->where('password', md5($password));
```